# using stack to index multiple columns by a single column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to take a format starting with:

```
 Global_Code | Retailer_X_Code | Retailer_Y_Code | Info | ...
  -----------------------------------------------------------
 'A'              'a'              'a_a'            1     ...
 'B'              'b'              'b_b'            2     ...
 ...              ...               ...            ...    ...
```

And stack the `Retailer_X_Code` and `Retailer_Y_Code` into a single `Retailer_Name` column, indexed by `Global_Code`. I'd also like to keep other columns in the row such as `Info`.

So starting off with `stack()`, I get:

```
 stacked_df = mapping_df.stack()

 ========

 Global_Code          'A'
 Retailer_X_Code      'a'
 Retailer_Y_Code      'a_a'
 Info                 1
 ...more columns

 Global_Code          'B'
 Retailer_X_Code      'b'
 Retailer_Y_Code      'b_b'
 Info                 2
 ...more columns
```

Great, now I don't all the columns, and want `Retailer_X_Code` and `Retailer_Y_Code` to be under one column. So I select these columns, organized by `Global_Code`:

```
stacked_df = mapping_df[['Global_Code', 'Retailer_X_Code', 'Retailer_Y_Code']].set_index('Global_Code').stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'Retailer_Name', 0:'Retailer_Code'})

========

Global_Code |  Retailer_Name   | Retailer_Code
------------------------------------------      
'A'           'Retailer_X_Code'   'a'         
'A'           'Retailer_Y_Code'   'a_a'          
...           ...                 ...              
'B'           'Retailer_X_Code'   'b'           
'B'           'Retailer_Y_Code'   'b_b'
```

**So far so good**. Now I want to grab `Info` and include is as part of the stacked column result. **The desired output should look like this:**

```
Global_Code |  Retailer_Name   | Retailer_Code | Info
------------------------------------------------------      
'A'           'Retailer_X_Code'   'a'            1
'A'           'Retailer_Y_Code'   'a_a'          1   
...           ...                 ...           ...    
'B'           'Retailer_X_Code'   'b'            2
'B'           'Retailer_Y_Code'   'b_b'          2
```

But if I add `Info` as part of the selected columns, then rename it to `Product_Info`, it doesn't add the `Info` column.

Instead, it inserts `Info` values incorrectly under `Retailer_Name`.

```
stacked_df = mapping_df[['Global_Code', 'Retailer_X_Code', 'Retailer_Y_Code', 'Info']].set_index('Global_Code').stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'Retailer_Name', 0:'Retailer_Code', 1: 'Product_Info'})

========

Global_Code |  Retailer_Name   | Retailer_Code
------------------------------------------      
'A'           'Retailer_X_Code'   'a'
'A'           'Retailer_Y_Code'   'a_a'
'A'           'Info'              1   
'A'           'Info'              1
'A'           'Info'              1            
...           ...                 ...
'B'           'Retailer_X_Code'   'b'
'B'           'Retailer_Y_Code'   'b_b'
'B'           'Info'              2
```

---

The above without column renaming, `.rename(columns={'level_1':'Retailer_Name', 0:'Retailer_Pack'})`, gives me:

```
Global_Code |  level_1          | 0
------------------------------------------      
'A'           'Retailer_X_Code'   'a'
'A'           'Retailer_Y_Code'   'a_a'
'A'           'Info'              1   
'A'           'Info'              1
'A'           'Info'              1            
...           ...                 ...
'B'           'Retailer_X_Code'   'b'
'B'           'Retailer_Y_Code'   'b_b'
'B'           'Info'              2
```

Comment: Without a reproducible example it is hard to say, but I suspect the last `rename` call may be where to look. What do you get from just ` mapping_df[['Global_Code', 'Retailer_X_Code', 'Retailer_Y_Code', 'Info']].set_index('Global_Code').stack().reset_index()`?

Comment: @ako simply gives me different columns names. See above

Comment: @ako I think I found the answer: add `Info` as an index (e.g., to `set_index` along with `Global_Code`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We using `wide_to_long`..:-), if you want to change the column name you can do , `rename`..

```
pd.wide_to_long(df,stubnames='Retailer',i=['Global_Code','Info'],j='Retailer_Name',sep='_',suffix='\\w+').reset_index()
Out[155]: 
  Global_Code  Info Retailer_Name Retailer
0         'A'     1        X_Code      'a'
1         'A'     1        Y_Code    'a_a'
2         'B'     2        X_Code      'b'
3         'B'     2        Y_Code    'b_b'
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Any benefit to this strategy rather than stacking on indices?

Comment: @Growler pd. wide_to_long is for this specific case , assuming you have  Retailer_X_Code to Retailer_Z_Code, and NORetailer_X_Code to NORetailer_Z_Code , list them all and setting index will be hard , but if we uing wide_to_long almost the same code above.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is `index` by the columns you need: `.set_index(['Index1', 'Index2'])`

E.g.:

```
stacked_df = mapping_df[['Global_Code', 'Retailer_X_Code', 'Retailer_Y_Code', 'Info']].set_index(['Global_Code', 'Info']).stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'Retailer_Name', 0:'Retailer_Code', 1: 'Product_Info'})
```

Gives:

```
Global_Code |  Info | Retailer_Name   | Retailer_Code 
------------------------------------------------------      
'A'              1    'Retailer_X_Code'   'a'           
'A'              1    'Retailer_Y_Code'   'a_a'           
...                   ...                 ...              
'B'              2    'Retailer_X_Code'   'b'           
'B'              2    'Retailer_Y_Code'   'b_b'
```